# Class "cache" not found - Prestashop

Tags: class, prestashop

I'm working on a prestashop friend's installation. So I took it from Github, set setting.php  to my localhost but I have the following error :

```
Class 'Cache' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prestashop/classes/ObjectModel.php on line 1470
```

But I don't know how to fix it :/

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

delete class_index.php if exists in cache folder.

Restore any cache folder you have deleted or ignored with .gitignore

This paths must exist in 1.5.6.2:

```
tools\tcpdf\cache
tools\swift\Swift\Cache
themes\default\cache
cache
cache\smarty\cache
classes\cache
override\classes\cache
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to know the version of Prestashop, you can see in **config/settings.inc.php** in prestashop 1.6.

Then check if the folder **/classes/cache** has the following files:

```
Cache.php
CacheApc.php
CacheMemcache.php
CacheMemcached.php
CacheXcache.php
index.php
```

If not get it from the installation archive for your local PS version.

And Last, delete **class_index.php** in cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have most probably downloaded version that is "work in progress" - such versions are only useful for people that would like to contribute to PrestaShop or want to check the development progress.

Downlaod the latest stable version from the official site and install it:
http://www.prestashop.com/en/download

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and I did the following:

1. restored cache folder in /prestashop/classes directory with following files inside cache folder:

   Cache.php, CacheApc.php, CacheFs.php, CacheMemcache.php, CacheMemcached.php, CacheXcache.php, index.php
2. restored the cache folder in /prestashop directory without    `class_index.php` 
   file

Got my problem solved :D